# show that if $\arctan(x)=\arctan(y)$ then $x=y$

Tags: real-analysis

show $$\arctan(x) =\arctan(y) \Rightarrow x=y$$

---

dont know where to start. appreciate a hint.

---

The problem started with showing that $d(x,y)=|\arctan(x)-\arctan(y)|$ is a metric. stuck on the property that $d(x,y)=0$ iff $x=y$

---

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\arctan$ is injective. This follows from the fact that $(\arctan)' = \frac{1}{1+x^2}$ is strictly positive.

Comment: How is $\arctan$ defined and how do you know derivative of $\arctan$?

Comment: @Ennar You have to be kidding. This objection is so pedantic and absurd it's not even worth responding to.

Comment: I'm trying to say that this is unnecessary, $\arctan$ is bijective by definition (unless you have something else in mind).

Comment: Well, you are actually being circular, derivative of $\arctan$ is calculated from derivative of $\tan$ using that it is it's inverse.

Comment: @Ennar Fine, let's work with $\arctan x := \int_0^x \frac{1}{1 + x^2}$.

Comment: Ennar's objection is neither pedantic nor absurd: *how* do you compute the derivative of the arctangent? Of course with the theorem about the derivative of the inverse function; so the arctangent is injective *because* it is defined as an inverse function. Your attempt at changing the deal doesn't help.

Comment: @egreg Circularity depends on the definition. You mentioned the limit of $\frac{\sin x}{x}$. Well, if we define $\sin$ as, say, a solution to a differential equation, is it still circular?

Comment: @egreg It's not implied anywhere by OP that $\arctan$ is defined as the inverse of $\tan$. This is most common definition (trigonometric), fair enough, but mathematically one definition is no better than the other and hence mathematically my answer is not wrong

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 Of course this depends on the definitions; can you point to some textbook that develops circular functions starting from $\arctan x=\int_{0}^x\frac{dt}{1+t^2}$?

Comment: @egreg Off hand, no, though it's not improbable that $\arctan$ has been defined as such somewhere. You could also define it in terms of its Maclaurin series. If you have a mathematical objection rather than one pertaining to conventions and textbook preferences, I'd love to hear it.

Comment: It is not about whether it is *technically* wrong or not, surely you could switch out any definition and characterization to suit your needs, but OP should be aware that $\arctan$ is injective by virtue of being inverse to $\tan$, however you develop those functions. I'm saying that you are pedagogically wrong.

Answer (score 6):

$\arctan$ is a bijection from $\mathbf R$ onto $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$, since it is the inverse function of the bijective restriction of $\tan$ to  $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$.

Comment: +1: the other answers use the derivative of the arctangent, but in order to compute it one has to define the arctangent to begin with. Since the arctangent is the inverse of the tangent over the interval $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$ it is obviously injective. Using the derivative here is somewhat like using l'Hôpital for proving that $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=1$.

Answer (score 1):

Assume $x \geq y$. By the [Mean Value Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem) we have that exists some $c\in\left[y,x\right]
 $ such that $$\arctan\left(x\right)-\arctan\left(y\right)=\frac{x-y}{1+c^{2}}\tag{1}$$ hence if the LHS of $(1)$ is zero we must have $x=y$.

Comment: Another downvote without any comment. It is very constructive.